# Can 一府两院 be replaced with 三院?

Tags: word-choice

Xinhua News Agency report of March 8, 2024:报告显示，一年来，全国人大常委会共听取审议“一府两院”22个报告，...

府 is like a big residence house or mansion, for example, 荣国府; 院 is a courtyard, but it is also a very active noun that can form other institutes like 电影院，医院，庭院，学院，养老院，etc.

Is 府 the short form of 中央政府？

What about 两院？China Academy of Sciences and China Academy of Engineering?

Can they be called 三院 as a whole since 中央政府 is actually 国务院？

Answer (score 2):

不可以。

“一府两院”指人民政府、人民法院和人民检察院。

“国务院”确实也就是“中央人民政府”。至于**不用“三院”的原因很简单：“地方人民政府”并不被称为“某某院”。**

在中国，中央人民政府（即国务院）、中央监察委员会、最高人民法院、最高人民检察院由全国人民代表大会产生，对它负责，受它监督。类似地，在各地方（省、直辖市、县、市、市辖区、乡、民族乡、镇等），地方人民政府、地方监察委员会、地方人民法院、地方人民检察院由地方人民代表大会产生，对它负责，受它监督。

现在也用“一府一委两院”的说法，“一委”指 2018 年新设的监察机关“监察委员会”。

Comment: Do you mean 最高人民法院 when you say 中央人民法院？

Comment: @NanningYouth I think yes since China don't have 中央人民法院 or 中央人民检察院, but 最高人民法院 and 最高人民检察院

Comment: @KaiKai They are 两高, but not 两院.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on Baidu, 府 would be 政府.

一委 seems to be missing in your quote:

> 一府两院一委”分别指：
>
> 一府。指人民政府，包括中央政府（如中华人民共和国国务院）和地方各级人民政府，负责执行和管理国家的行政事务，制定和实施国家政策，管理经济和社会发展，保障公民的基本权利和需求，维护国家安全和社会稳定。
> 一委。指监察委员会，是2018年根据国家监察体制改革设立的新机构，主要职责是监督、调查和处理公职人员的违法违纪行为，实现了对所有行使公权力的公职人员的监察全覆盖。
> 两院。指人民法院和人民检察院，其中人民法院是国家的审判机关，负责依法审理刑事、民事和行政案件，确保法律的正确执行和司法公正；人民检察院是国家的法律监督机关，负责提起公诉、监督刑事诉讼过程、监督法院的审判活动等，确保司法公正和法律的正确执行。

Comment: It is a bit unusual, isn't it? Because most of the times they use 政 to refer to 政府, for example, 各地党政机关，党政一把手，but never 党府机关, 党府一把手, but 官府 is used in some novels.

Comment: I believe the phrase should be taken together: 一府两院 people's government, court and procuratorate As it says above: 一府。指人民政府

Comment: Yes, the single character 府 is not to imply government, but often leads a reader to the meaning of residence of high-ranking officials or wealthy people.  Even used as you said, the phrase is still risky to the user if the reader has an ulterior motive.

Comment: Not so sure I can agree with you. This from zdic.net : 府: 国家行政机关：政府。官府。

Comment: To further illustrate my point, I would give an example 一位总书记和一位国家主席, it is OK to say 一书记一主席， but not 一书一席

Comment: I often have problems caused by this: Chinese, having perfectly understandable 2 character words, such as 政府, applying a logic unknown to me, choose to omit 1 character. Chinese people, reading the single character, know from the context what word is intended by the 1 character. I often flounder. 也可以写"一政一委两院"

Comment: 两院 often mean the two academies of sciences, hence 两院院士, the 两院 the above are known as 两高.

Comment: I do not disagree with you about the possible meanings of 两院. But meanings are context dependent. In this context, the article I quoted states 院 is 法院: 两院。指人民法院和人民检察院. I accept this designation as correct in this context. Both courts enforce the law.

Answer (score 0):

> What about 两院？China Academy of Sciences and China Academy of Engineering?

"三院" could be a valid suggestion, but officially,

“一府”是指人民政府，**“两院”是指人民法院、人民检察院**。在中国，国家行政机关、审判机关、检察机关都由作为国家权力机关的人民代表大会产生，对它负责，受它监督。国家机构按照的民主集中制原则活动。

**在中央部门中，“府”主要是指中华人民共和国国务院**，“两院”主要是指中华人民共和国最高人民法院、中华人民共和国最高人民检察院，一府两院都由全国人民代表大会产生，对全国人大负责，受其监督。

**国家监察体制改革设立监察委员会作为专门的反腐败工作机构，与国家行政机关、审判机关和检察机关平行，“一府两院”变为“一府一委两院”**。

https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%80%E5%BA%9C%E4%B8%A4%E9%99%A2/8991077